# How to remove items in the constantly updated block

Tags: javascript

**HTML:**

```
<select name="selectt" id="select" class="data_field">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
</select>
```

How can I delete all `option`s? Trying to get them using the following JavaScript:

**JS**

```
select_prod.querySelectorAll('select>option');
```

`for` is not an option because another `select` uploads new `option`s in this select. So old one `option`s goes away and replacing them with new ones.

Comment: what is `select_prod`?

Comment: Assuming `select_prod` is a reference to the `<select>` element, couldn't you just do `select_prod.innerHTML = ''`?

Comment: im sorry , that is `select` .. updated question

Comment: It still looks like there's a typo; did you mean `var select = document.getElementById('select')`?

Comment: yes i could . but this options are always changing . so by clickin on another  the same block this block of select are updating. so that is why i need to delete "old ones" options

Answer (score 1):

> how can i delete all options? tryin to get them js

you can do it as

```
var alloptions = document.getElementById( "select" ).children; //get all options
document.getElementById( "select" ).innerHTML = "";//delete all options
```

> for is not an option cuz another select uploads new options in this
>   select.

Javasript execution inside a browser is a single threaded operation, there is no chance of another `select` making changes inside your `select` while the above is being executed.

Comment: Good answer. Though I'm not sure he needs to save the options as you've done here in an `alloptions` variable.

Comment: so after this im kind of gettin few empty options and a new ones

Comment: like this 
`<option></option>
<option></option>
<option></option>
<option>new text</option>
<option>new text</option>`

Answer (score 0):

To remove the options, it is as simple as setting the length to zero.

```
 document.getElementById('select').options.length = 0;
```